# Graph theory basics

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question just to verify myself with some graph theory questions as I have forgotten most of my graph theory since highschool. This is the exercise i found from my old high school archives:

This is what i think the answers are:

The first three are all Eulerian Circuits, then Hamiltonian Circuit then Hamiltonian Path.

I basically get like the general idea behind what circuits paths and are but it is so confusing when I have to distinguish the different kinds like I have no problem with like proofs to graph theory results but these kind of questions confuse me so much.

Could anyone help me check my answers?

( I cannot seem to find the homework and exercises tag).

[image]

Comment: The second one is a Hamiltonian circuit.  He just has to visit the parks, not traverse all the streets between the parks.  Otherwise, I agree with your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I understood, the first four are all returning to where they begun, so they are all circuits.

$a-$Eulerian Circuit

$b-$Hamiltonian Circuit

$c-$Eulerian Circuit

$d-$Hamiltonian Circuit

$e-$Hamiltonian Path

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful